# scenario based on each file format in hive

Tags: hadoop

am new to Hadoop. Just now learning to attend the interviews. there are some questions were asked in the interview like, what is the size of the tables and what is the underlying file formats for it? how many rows are there etc.. which am unable to satisfy the interviewer. Please let me know any scenario based for file formats in Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Hive would not tell you the size of the table. You need to sum up the HDFS directories consisting of the table.

You can find the format of the table by describing it. If you knew Hive, you should understand what command use for this.

Similarly, HiveQL has a count SQL operator for getting the number of rows. File format doesn't matter